# Show pop up after redirect

Tags: javascript, php

In my script below,a pop-up displays first then when I click ok, I'm redirected to the `editproduct.php` page. I would like it to first redirect me to the `editproduct.php` page then display the popup there .

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Only images allowed'); window.location.href = 'editproduct.php?post=$post';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the following way by appending a class to the body tag.

```
<body class="<?php
if(isset($_GET['show_popup'])){
   if($_POST['show_popup'] == 'true'){
      echo 'show-popup';
   }
}?>"></body>
```

then use jQuery to show the popup.

```
if($('.show-popup').length > 0){
    alert('popup');
}
```

You would have to pass a param in the URL

```
editproduct.php?post=$post&show_popup=true
```

this a pretty basic approach.